# Android STS (Security Test Suite)

Tags: android, testing, sts

a question regarding Android STS (Security Test Suite). Is a binary available to download? Or what is the way to run this suite? Thanks

Comment: https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/sts-sdk

Comment: Thanks, but its only the SDK for developing own tests, i'm looking for something similar to cts package

Answer (score 0):

Android STS tool is available for download to Android Partners. So you must be registered and have an access to docs.partner.android.com/security in order to download the tools.